# What are the mechanisms for the propagation of effects across stages in a structural model?

Tags: estimation, covariance, structural-equation-modeling

I have an SEM question to which I have not found an answer anywhere. I have used SEM a bit already but my difficulties with this question suggest I lack some basic understanding.

Question:
In a structural model involving chains of paths as long as four or five paths (a multistage model, e.g., as in x1 -> x2 -> x3 and x4 -> x5 and x6 -> x7 and x8), some of which stages thus contains several parallel variables and paths, I find that the ML estimates of the path coefficients in early parts of the model (early stages) change when I adjust later parts of the model (i.e., when I insert an additional stage just prior to the final variable by means of a new variable with paths to it and from it, or when I separate an existing latent factor in a late stage into two different latent factors). The changed estimates for the early path coefficients happen as far away from the inserted or split (divided in two) variables as two paths away (e.g., paths from x3 and x4 are affected by new insertions just before x7 and x8).

The changes in the early path coefficients are substantial and involve change of sign as well as change of statistical significance. (The intermediate path coefficients between the newly inserted paths and the affected earlier paths change too.)

Do my adjustments late in the model (i.e., in later stages close to the final dependent variables) somehow back propagate by creating changed residual variance in earlier variables to which earlier variables are connected, such that the paths to this residual variance in the earlier stages is affected? It is clear how addition or removal of covariates can affect coefficients in a multiple regression, but it is unclear (to me) whether something similar could be going on (and in that case how) even across several paths in a structural model of an SEM, which is based on a covariance matrix fitting. What is the mechanism whereby changes in one place can affect paths in another place? Does the mechanism involve the residual (co)variances (perhaps even in a way that could allow me to anticipate what the changes might be of adding or removing paths even far away in the model)?

I have used STATA to carry out the analyses.

Thanks very much for any advice on how to understand (or deal with) this.

Answer (score 1):

Standard maximum likelihood estimation searches for estimates that simultaneously minimize all discrepancies between observed and expected (model-implied) (means and co)variances.  This makes it subject to "propagation of errors", which some SEM textbooks discuss (e.g., [Kline](https://www.guilford.com/books/Principles-and-Practice-of-Structural-Equation-Modeling/Rex-Kline/9781462551910) or [Loehlin](https://doi.org/10.4324/9781315643199)).  Most (un)weighted least-squares estimators (including GLS) are also subject to this.  But Bollen ([1996](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02296961)) introduced two-stage least-squares (2SLS) estimation that solves for paths equation by equation.  This is not immune, but is much less susceptible to, propagation of errors.  I'm not sure about Stata, but I know this estimator is implemented in R using the [MIIVsem package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MIIVsem) (see lots of details on the `?miive` help page).